# MySQL Simple Router Config - Dump metadata-cache-d Destination server value

Tags: mysql, mysqlrouter

This is part of the config

```
[routing:MYCLUSTER_x_rw]
bind_address=0.0.0.0
bind_port=3308
socket=/opt/mysql/MYCLUSTER_x_rw/mysqlx.sock
destinations=metadata-cache://MYCLUSTER_x_rw/?role=PRIMARY   #  <----- I need to know the host names
routing_strategy=first-available
protocol=x
```

I need to figure out what is the actual `destinations` key's value going to be once the router is going to start up. How do I find that out?

Answer (score -2):

Have a look at the [configuration file options documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-router/8.0/en/mysql-router-conf-options.html#option_mysqlrouter_destinations).

In short, just change `MYCLUSTER_x_rw` to the name of the cluster you created. If you created the mysql innodb cluster by shell as  `dba.createCluster('testCluster');`, then in the config file you should write
`destinations=metadata-cache://testCluster/?role=PRIMARY`.

Please notice, if you use metadata-cache for destinations, you have to define it in the config file as below:

```
[metadata_cache:bootstrap]
cluster_type=gr
router_id=1
user=mysql_router1_ppwqrnhzsbj9
metadata_cluster=testCluster
ttl=0.5
auth_cache_ttl=-1
auth_cache_refresh_interval=2
use_gr_notifications=0
```

Here is [another example of the full config file](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-router/8.0/en/mysql-router-configuration-file-example.html).